# Why updateValueAndValidity is not updating the value of form Controls in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, issue-tracking

I have recently migrated from Angular 9 to Angular 12 and observing form control value issue. Below are the details of the issue:

1. I have a dropdown control, based on the value selected there are
   controls which has to update the value according to my model,
2. When value of dropdown control is changed , my dependent controls
   value is not updating according to the model, in code debug my form
   is having the value based on the changes done to drop down, even
   though this.form.updateValueAndValidity(); applied, changes are not
   reflected in the UI.

**Here is the HTML file**

```
<div class="form-control">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="type">Type</label>
    <select id="type" name="Selection" formControlName="Type">
        <option value="null" selected="true" id="default">Select type...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of supportedTypes" [value]="item.Type" id="{{item.Type}}">{item.ShortName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>


//Below controls are dependent on the above value selected, for each selection change different values to be display

<div class="form-control">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="type">Type</label>
    <select id="type" name="Selection" formControlName="Type">
        <option value="null" selected="true" id="default">Select type...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of supportedTypes" [value]="item.Type" id="{{item.Type}}">{{item.ShortName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="form-control tooltip">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <input type="text" maxlength=13 formControlName="Name" id="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control tooltip">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="age">Age</label>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <input type="text" formControlName="Age" NumberOnly="true" id="age">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control tooltip">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="Height">Height</label>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <input type="text" formControlName="Height" NumberOnly="true" id="height">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control tooltip">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="weight">Weight (kg)</label>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <input type="text" NumberOnly="true" formControlName="Weight" id="weight">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**file which has to update the value**

this method is for updating my form contols

```js
updateControls(show: boolean, formMeta: object, data?: { [key: string]: string }) 
{
  Object.keys(formMeta).forEach((formName) => 
  {
    if (!show)
    {
      //remove control if none selected
      this.form.removeControl(formName);
      return;
    }
    //add controls on value change and update the controls
    this.form.addControl(formName, formMeta[formName]);
    this.form.get(formName).patchValue(data[formName]);
  });

  this.form.updateValueAndValidity();    //update my form, but it doesn't reflect the updated content in UI     
}
```